# Serverside script stop working after heavy usage

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

i have build a tabbed application with XPages.
My problem is, when i open to fast to much tabs, every serverside script stop working.
I get still a partial refresh but he did not execute any serverside script. After a full refresh every think works again. I can reproduce this an every server.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

UPDATE (more details)
I work with iframes and in every tab i create a complex view (with a repeater)
I've i open the tabs not to fast everything works just perfect, but if i open the tabs to fast nothing will work, it affects to every script.

I got no clientside script error and i got also no serverside scipt error.
Some of these scripts are simple like document.replaceItemValue("fieldname", "value");
I've set just a print statement in the function but it also won't execute.

It seems that the server deletes the xpages session if he comes in memory trouble

Comment: Maybe a problem with your code? Can you add more Details what you are doing and/or add some Code snippets to your question?

Comment: If you modify the xsp.persistence.tree.maxviews or asp.persistence.file.maxviews does the issue still persist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for the problem is, i have to increase the number for the xsp.persistence.file.maxviews property

Comment: Interesting, I thought that setting had nothing to do with how fast you open the tabs.

Answer (score 3):

You need to check carefully. It sounds less than a "heavy" usage and more like a concurrency problem. Be aware that any variable you define in a script library is application scoped. If multiple calls update the same value you might experience such a behavior. The scope variables are there to keep values.